# Need help with samba and XBMC

Tags: server, windows-7, samba, xbmc, smb

I have honestly spent at least 6 to 8 hours trying to get this to work. Here's what I've got.

Ubuntu-server file server
Rasberry Pi with Xbian
Several Windows 7 Machines

I've set up a samba share on the ubuntu server. I can access it from the Windows Machines without logging in at all but I have to manually type the address (\Gandalf\Shares). It doesn't show up in my network automatically (I'd like it to but whatever).

The problem I'm having is accessing it from XBMC. I can't access it from my Rasberry or XBMC on my windows machines no matter how I try to get to it. It seems like I get a different error everytime.

Here's the kicker, When I first got my rasberry I set all this up and it all worked perfectly. I could see it on any windows 7 machine on the network and I could get to it right from the file manager in xbmc. It took me about 30 minutes of Googling and trial and error so I had no idea it would be so difficult to do again. But since then I reinstalled xbian on the pi and reinstalled Ubuntu-server on the linux box. Essentially, I started from scratch with the same config.

I'm really pulling my hair out over this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my smb.conf file

```
[global]
    ; General server settings
    netbios name = Gandalf
    server string =
    workgroup = FELLOWSHIP
    announce version = 5.0
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_$
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    security = user
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    name resolve order = hosts wins bcast

    wins support = yes

    syslog = 1
    syslog only = yes

    map to guest = bad user

; NOTE: If you need access to the user home directories uncomment the
; lines below and adjust the settings to your hearts content.
;[homes]
    ;valid users = %S
    ;create mode = 0600
    ;directory mode = 0755
    ;browseable = no
    ;read only = no
    ;veto files = /*.{*}/.*/mail/bin/

; NOTE: Only needed if you run samba as a primary domain controller.
; Not needed as this config doesn't cover that matter.
;[netlogon]
    ;path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
    ;admin users = Administrator
    ;valid users = %U
    ;read only = no

; NOTE: Again - only needed if you're running a primary domain controller.
;[Profiles]
    ;path = /var/lib/samba/profiles
    ;valid users = %U
    ;create mode = 0600
    ;directory mode = 0700
    ;writeable = yes
    ;browseable = no

[Shares]
path = /shares
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
#create mask = 0775
#directory mask = 0775
writeable = yes
available = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got this figured-out, but when I was setting up shares in Ubuntu 12.04 I had to do a couple things before I was able to see them from a Windows machine:

1. Create a Samba username and password (***sudo smbpasswd -a
   USERNAME***)
2. In the file manager (not sure if that's the right name), on the
   Linux machine I set the permissions to ***Owner, Group, and
   Others***. And set the Access to ***Create and Delete Files***.

Hope this helps.